# iptables rules work inbound, but not outbound

Tags: linux, rhel, iptables

I have 5 Windows workstations (on various versions) connected to an unmanaged switch, which then connects to a NAS running Samba, which then pushes the data out to our storage cluster. That's been problematic for a variety of reasons, so I'm turning the NAS into a FW to allow traffic directly to our storage cluster. All this aside... I got this working, but I don't understand **why** it's working, and it's really bothering me. Here's what I did.

If it matters, this is a RHEL 6 server. I'm not sure what version of iptables is running, at the moment... I'm not on my work computer to look at it.

Interface em1 connects to the DMZ, and interface em2 is the private network.

If I set these rules, everything passes, but it also gives the workstations access to the open internet, which is non-compliant.

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth2 -j ACCEPT
```

So I set these to allow outbound connectivity only to the services I need.

```
-A FORWARD -i em2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <DNS> -o em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <DNS> -o em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o em2 -p tcp -m multiport --ports 137,138,139,445 -m iprange --dst-range <STORAGE> -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 137,138,139,445 -m iprange --dst-range <STORAGE> -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <NTP> -o em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 123 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

This fails to connect, but if I flip these around, everything works!

```
-A FORWARD -o em2 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <DNS> -i em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <DNS> -i em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 53 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <FreeIPA> -p tcp -m multiport --ports 88 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i em2 -p tcp -m multiport --ports 137,138,139,445 -m iprange --dst-range <STORAGE> -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 137,138,139,445 -m iprange --dst-range <STORAGE> -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d <NTP> -i em2 -p udp -m multiport --ports 123 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

It seems that this works because *--ports* matches 53, 88, etc., to the source port of the inbound traffic. I don't know why the outbound rules don't match those to the destination ports. When I used *--dports* instead of *--ports*, it didn't work, which is why I switched to *--ports*. So I'm lost... can anyone explain this to me? I feel like such an idiot.

Comment: Requests from the Private network (em2) are going *into* the firewall, hence the `-i em2`. This allows devices connected to `em2` to talk to the firewall which then inevitably gets routed out to the DMZ

Comment: Okay, I think I'm confusing the way iptables does things because it's not quite the same as standalone FWs (Fortinet, Palo Alto, whatever)...

I was thinking traffic goes like privNW > em2 [NAT changes outbound to em1] > external NW

And then return traffic goes ExternalNW > em1 [NAT changes out dest to em2] > privNW. 

So why does traffic coming from <DNS>:53 not hit a source port rule and allow it OUT of em2 to the private network?

Comment: iptables is a stateful firewall engine, so it'll keep track of outbound connections and assume that inbound connections that are a reply to an outbound connection should be allowed, so it doesn't need an explicit rule to allow it back into the private network.